# solve for x inside of a sum when n is defined (not infinity)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, summation

I decided to try this with a simple sum I made

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{x}{i}} = 3$$

I know the basic properties of sums, and I tried solving this with the properties; $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{i} = \frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{c} = nc$

Doing so gave me this:

$$\frac{nx}{\sum_{i = 4}^{n}{i}} =3$$
Which I simplified into
$$\frac{nx}{\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)} = 3$$ 
and then finally,
$$x = \frac{3}{2n}n(n+1)$$
and when refined;
$$x = \frac{3n + 3}{2}$$

Which I tried to solve using $n=4$, but got $\frac{30}{8}$ which when plugged into the same sum with $n=4$ returned $\frac{25^2}{4^2}$ for reasons I do not know. I do know that $\frac{125}{16} \ne 3$, so where did I go wrong, and how do I solve this correctly? I'm not a calculus student, I'm actually an algebra II student, so please keep it to simple stuff like limits and sums, which is about all I understand.

Comment: 1/2+1/3is not 1/(2+3)

Comment: "Doing so gave me this:

4x∑ni=4i=3"  How???????

Comment: @ fleablood I have a summation evaluator on my Ti-84 in which I plugged in for x

Comment: I meant how did you figure that $\sum i = \frac 12n(n+1)$ and $\sum c = nc$ would mean $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac xi = \frac {nx}{\sum_{i=4} i}$?????  How on earth does *that* follow????

Comment: @fleablood I'm algebra oriented, this is how I think. I don't know where the train of thought came form, but It came from somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true that $$\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{x}{i} = \dfrac{nx}{\sum_{i=1}^n i}$$

However, you can just factor out the $x$ since it does not depend on $i$ and find $$x= \dfrac{3}{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}}$$

The numbers $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}$ are known as [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). I am unaware of any 'nice' formula for them in general - at least any that make the formula already nicer than it is.

Comment: from what I just read on wikipedia article linked in a comment, this would be a nicer solution: $$x = \frac{3}{H_{n}}$$

Comment: You can use the approximation that $H_n\approx \ln n+\gamma$, where $\gamma \approx 0.577$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant)

Comment: @Coderboy Your "nicer solution" is _exactly the same_ solution.

Comment: @David I mean nicer to the eyes, I hate seeing $\sum$ in a denominator

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{x}{i}} \neq {\frac{nx}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}i}}$$

Comment: is there a property for $\sum^{n}_{i=1}{i^{-1}}$ that will help me?

Comment: @Coderboy Note for example that n=2 that $\frac{x}{1}+\frac{x}{2}=\frac{3x}{2}$

Comment: @Coderboy You are looking for the sum of Harmonic series, take a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)

Comment: @Coderboy And here for the partal sum https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Partial_sums

Comment: @gimusi good one !